# Enabling CORS for js

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess

HeIIo, I'm trying to create a small service, that would add some functionality to a webpage. The user inserts the following code on his website.

```
<script src="http://mywebsite.com/code.js"></script>
```

The purpose of this code is loading of an html element with the following request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mywebsite.com/element.html",
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
    },
    headers: {
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('body').append(data);
    }
});
```

The problem is that I always get `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://mywebsite.com/element.html. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

I tried recommendations from this [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), but still getting the same errors. I also put the following row in .htaccess file: `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` - still no result. I would appreciate any recommendations on how else I can enable CORS.

Comment: `contentType: 'text/plain',` — Why do you have this? You are making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content type of!

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Reload the page. Can you see your Ajax request in the Net tab? Is it formatted correctly? Does it get a response? Is the response correct? i.e. Can you see the **GET** request? Can you see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: no, I don't see Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, the rest of GET look normal

Comment: well, I mean what I'm sending is correct, but there is no response

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header. You need to look for it on the response.

Comment: `200` is the HTTP status code for `OK` and is part of the response. You can't have it unless there is a response. (If you didn't have one, you'd have a time out error)

Comment: ok, see it, the response headers are:
Connection: keep-alive, 
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html,
Date: Sun, 31 Aug 2014 13:12:55 GMT,
Last-Modified: Mon, 18 Aug 2014 19:22:38 GMT,
Server: nginx/1.6.1,
Transfer-Encoding: chunked. 

So there is no header that we are looking for. How can I add it?

Comment: well, I found a problem, I was using SET instead of ADD. Correct .htaccess: is Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"

Comment: I appreciate your help and patience, I really learned something from you, thanks